# How to read a list of values in app.config and populate a combo (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I have 5 different connectionStrings in my app.config file and would like to populate a combo with these values. How can I acheve this in VB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the `System.Configuration dll`. Then you can get all connection-strings with the [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) class:

```
Dim allConnections = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
For Each connection As ConnectionStringSettings In allConnections
    Dim connectionName = connection.Name
    Dim connectionString = allConnections(connection.Name).ConnectionString
    ddlConnections.Items.Add(connectionName)
Next
```

I assume that you don't want to show the full connection string but only it's name.

Answer (score 0):

use loop and get the all connection string like this

```
   loop Start
   //add your desired code
   Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item(i)

   loop end
```